# interact with android input controls by java application

Tags: java, android, adb

I'm trying to interact with android input controls on my android device, such as Buttons, textfields, etc.
What I'm trying to do is whenever i click on an input control, that can be added to a list in my java application.
Can I use adb commands on that? Does anyone have any other ideas about this issue?

Any hints and help for this :)

Comment: you may want to take a look at webdriver and selendroid

Answer (score 0):

Take EditText widget for Example:

1. Create layout xml containing EditText(id = myEditText) and ListView(id = myListView).
2. Within onCreate of one of your Activity, get references to above two UI widgets

   ```
   final EditText myEditText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
   ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
   ```
3. Still in onCreate, Define an ArrayList and ArrayAdapter which bind the ArrayList to ListView

   ```
   final ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
   final ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al); 

   myListView.setAdapter(aa);
   ```
4. Add a onKeyListener to the EditText widget, listen for EnterKey and dpad_center key

   ```
   myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
           public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) ||
                           (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) ) {
                       al.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                       aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       myEditText.setText("");
                       return true;
                   }
               return false;
           }
       });
   ```